# Natural alignment TTTAttributedLabel for Right Aligned Languages

Tags: ios, iphone, text-alignment, right-align, tttattributedlabel

I'm using TTTAttributedLabel in my applications, now when I tried to add Right aligned languages, I encountered an issue that it doesn't support natural alignment for RTL, text is left aligned for RTL too, any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

simply, set textAlignment to right like this

```
tttLabel.textAlignment = .right
```